# How can I delete all xprint jobs for one printer?

Tags: printing

I've got several printers configured in my xprint. Now I would like to delete all print jobs of one printer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
xpdel -job -scl "-de *PRINTERNAME*"
```